# How to keep data in a hash map

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am able to print the  the data like below:

```
id    comes_in
___   ________
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       3
```

where both id and comes_in are integers.Now I want to keep this in a hashmap where key is the comes_in and values are an arraylist of ids.

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new  HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

So it will be like below:

```
comes_in     id
________     ___
1             1,2,3 
2             4,5
3             6
```

But the problem is how to put them in a hashmap because Initially I am unable to group the id by comes_in.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your sample made me confused. Shouldn't comes_in of id 4 and id 5 be 2?

Comment: Yeah sorry updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java 8 Stream. Your quest could be achieved easily.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-

```
public class TestProgram {
  public static void main(String...args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(2, 1);
    map.put(3, 1);
    map.put(4, 2);
    map.put(5, 2);
    map.put(6, 3);

    Map<Object, List<Object>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
              Entry::getValue, 
              HashMap::new, 
              Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
            ));
    System.out.println(result);
    // {1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[4, 5], 3=[6]}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know the use of the stream